# How do I call a function in my ViewController from my NSWindow?

Tags: macos, swift, cocoa

I am using Swift and Storyboards. I can't figure out how to access my ViewController from my NSWindow. Storyboard doesn't seem to allow me to create an outlet from one to the other. I am sure there is some easy way to do this.

Edit: Why is this not possible?

[image]

Comment: Please share some code where you are you trying to access the viewController

Answer (score 7):

From my NSWindow I was able to access the NSViewController like so:

```
let controller = self.windowController()?.contentViewController as! ViewController;
```

where `ViewController` is the name of my ViewController subclass of NSViewController.

It is still not clear to me why I cannot just create an Outlet using Storyboard.